# Export iOS IPA file with eclipse (libGDX/RoboVM)

Tags: ios, eclipse, libgdx, ipa, robovm

I'm trying to export my iOS libGDX project and I followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Deploying-your-application). I have everything setup in iTunes Connect and I have both my Developer and Distribution Signing Certificates. I right click my iOS project in eclipse, choose RoboVM Tools --> Package for App Store/Ad-Hoc distribution, filled out the required fields and I get a message from Console saying

> 10/26/14 3:31:57 AM: [ INFO] Creating package in /Users/Me/Documents/myJavaStuff/myIOS Game/iOS IPA ...

But nothing happens after that. No error message, no other console messages and no file to import to Apple. Anyone else experience this?

Would this have anything to do with my info.plist.xml. I didn't touch a lot of these key strings except for CFBundleIdentifier

```
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>en</string>
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>${app.name}</string>
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
<string>${app.executable}</string>
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>com.myertha.paperpig</string>
<key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
<string>6.0</string>
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>${app.name}</string>
<key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
<string>APPL</string>
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>${app.version}</string>
```

Comment: Besides the basic question: "Did you look into that folder?" :D, try to update your robovm and libgdx libraries!

Comment: Everything is updated... I'm using libGDX version 1.4.1 and I updated all my RoboVM libraries in eclipse.

Comment: Does your path contain UTF-8 characters or is extremely big? Thats odd cause that message is only a Warning. It should have created the IPA correctly

Comment: All the characters in my game are images created with Hiero.. largest font atlas is 45kb. My game runs fine on the iOS simulator. I just can't export it because nothing happens besides that message above.

Comment: I'm talking about the export destination folder (aka path). Does it contains UTF-8 characters or is extremely big?

Comment: no.. the path are just letters, and there's nothing in that folder. This is my exact path /Users/Erwin/Documents/myJavaStuff/PaperPig Game/iOS IPA

Comment: Are you waiting long enough? It can take ten minutes or so the first time you compile robovm.

Comment: Did you provide supported orientations in the info.plist? See the common info.plist and compare to yours! Here:https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests-iosrobovm/Info.plist.xml

Comment: I've waited and my info.plist has the proper orientations. Still nothing..

Answer (score 0):

Well... I finally got it to work, but I took a route I was hoping I wouldn't take. I reinstalled my Eclipse, and all the different required plug-ins (Gradle, ADT, RoboVM, etc). Process which took an more than an hour. I was in Eclipse ver 4.3 but now I'm using 4.4 which is Eclipse Luna. But other than that, everything else is still the same but I am now able to export using RoboVM Tools --> Package for App Store/Ad-Hoc distribution. Weird, but whatever works...